# How to create new columns from rows value

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark

I want to create new columns from rows value using spark sql 2.x and java 8 ; something like that :

Original :

```
POLICY_NO | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |    DOB      |  SEX |
--------------------------------------------------------
1234      |   JOHN     |   HILL    |  01/01/1978 |  0   |
1234      |   JILL     |   HILL    |  10/10/1980 |  1   |
5678      |   JAMES    |   PIKE    |  05/05/1950 |  0   |
5678      |   JOAN     |   MAY     |  04/04/1955 |  1   |
```

expected results :

```
POLICY_NO | FIRST_NAME |    LAST_NAME |      DOB   | SEX  | FIRST_NAME2  | LAST_NAME2   | DOB2          | SEX2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234      |   JOHN     |   HILL       | 01/01/1978 | 0    | JILL         |    HILL      |   10/10/1980  |   1
5678      |   JAMES    |   PIKE       | 05/05/1950 | 0    | JOAN         |    MAY       |   04/04/1955  |   1
```

Thank you

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function.

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT POLICY_NO,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 0 THEN FIRST_NAME END) FIRST_NAME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 0 THEN LAST_NAME END) LAST_NAME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 0 THEN DOB END) DOB,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 0 THEN SEX END) SEX,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 1 THEN FIRST_NAME END) FIRST_NAME2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 1 THEN LAST_NAME END) LAST_NAME2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 1 THEN DOB END) DOB2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEX= 1 THEN SEX END) SEX2
FROM T
GROUP BY POLICY_NO;

| POLICY_NO | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | DOB        | SEX | FIRST_NAME2 | LAST_NAME2 | DOB2       | SEX2 |
| --------- | ---------- | --------- | ---------- | --- | ----------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---- |
| 1234      | JOHN       | HILL      | 01/01/1978 | 0   | JILL        | HILL       | 10/10/1980 | 1    |
| 5678      | JAMES      | PIKE      | 05/05/1950 | 0   | JOAN        | MAY        | 04/04/1955 | 1    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/HV95KRo55c3NMnQuB6jcx/0)

Comment: Thank you D-Shih. Any idea to make it dynamic ( for any input )

Comment: @Mks If you are using a programming language then just include identified grouping column. But if you have more than one person as in this case sharing a policy number then you will have more columns. That I believe may not be possible programmatically. You may need to make the additional columns as an array.

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil. I will try this